# Show that every continuous finite rank operator $T$ can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i x_i \otimes y_i$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Can someone help me with this question?

Suppose that $H$ and $K$ are Hilbert spaces. Show that every operator $T \in B_{00}(H, K)$ can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i x_i \otimes y_i$, where $\{ x_i \} \subseteq H$ and $\{ y_i \} \subseteq K$ are orthonormal sets.

Also, show that $T \in B_{00}(H, H)$ can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i x_i \otimes x_i$, where $\{ x_i \} \subseteq H$ is an orthonormal set.

**Definition:** $B_{00}(H, K)$ is the space of all continuous finite rank operators from $H$ to $K$.

**Definition:** Given Hilbert space $H$, and $x, y \in H$, the rank one operator $x \otimes y$ is defined with $(x \otimes y)(z) = \langle z, y \rangle \ x.$

I think we should consider range of $T$ that is finite dimensional, so has a finite orthonormal basis, and then use Parseval's identity to write $T(z)$ as linear combination of elements in the basis. But I can't prove the statement in this way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose \circle\circle means \infty?

Comment: @Freeze_S No, that was \circ, that I correct it.

Comment: I half expect that should rather be $B_{00}(H,K)$.

Comment: In the case of different spaces, consider the restriction to $(\ker T)^\perp$, then you are in the finite-dimensional setting. In the case of $T\colon H \to H$, some further condition is necessary, $T\colon x \mapsto \langle e_1,x\rangle\cdot e_2$, where $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is part of an orthonormal basis, cannot be written in the form $\sum \lambda_i x_i \otimes x_i$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Why $x \overset{T}{\mapsto} \langle e_1, x \rangle . e_2$ cannot be written in that form?

Comment: Because $T\circ T = 0$, and $T\neq 0$. But for $S = \sum \lambda_i x_i \otimes x_i$,. if there is an $i_0$ with $\lambda_{i_0} \neq 0$, then $x_{i_0}$ is an eigenvector to the eigenvalue $\lambda_{i_0} \neq 0$, so $(S\circ S)(x_{i_0}) = \lambda_{i_0}^2\cdot x_{i_0} \neq 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer very nice, thanks. Can we disprove the statement in the case of different spaces in a same way?

Comment: No, if we want a representation $\sum \lambda_i x_i \otimes y_i$, that exists. It's only the restriction that both arguments of $\otimes$ shall be the same that requires further properties than finite rank.

Comment: OK, thank you @DanielFischer